# How to avoid potential race condition involving Node.js, Redis and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multithreading, redis

In my application, I am generating unique IDs using Redis. The ID generation algorithm is this:

```
new_id = INCR last_id
FindAndModify(last_id, new_id)
return new_id
```

`last_id` is simply the previously generated ID, `INCR` is the Redis command which atomically increments a key and `FindAndModify` is an atomic operation on MongoDB to update a document.

I am using MongoDB along with Redis just to give extra protection against failures. So, whenever I generate a new ID, I first check the last ID in Redis, if I cant get it from there (due to Redis failure), I will get it from MongoDB. So, the Redis and MongoDB instances have to be in sync.

Now, I am worried about race conditions in 2 situations:

1. Single Node.js instance
2. Multiple Node.js instances

In case 1, since Node.js is single threaded, it probably wont cause race conditions, but its also asynchronous, so I am not very sure about it. Can there be race conditions in this situtation?

In case 2, there will definitely be race conditions. Consider this sequence:

```
Process1: INCR last_id ----> returns 1
Process2: INCR last_id ----> returns 2
Process2: FindAndModify(last_id, 2)
Process1: FindAndModify(last_id, 1)
```

Here, finally, `last_id` should have been `2` but due to the race condition its value will be `1`.

If I only had MongoDB OR Redis, this wouldnt have been an issue as both `INCR` and `FindAndModify` are atomic. Even if they were not atomic, with only Redis or only MongoDB, I could have simply used transactions. But how do I deal with this, when both Redis and MongoDB are involved? Is this even possible? AFAIK Node.js and Javascript is single threaded so there arent any threads or thread synchronisation constructs available to deal with this at the application level.

Comment: Are you using Redis replication? Why do think Redis will have lower availability than Mongo?

Comment: I probably will use replication for both MongoDB and Redis, but I am wondering how exactly are these issues dealt with for a real system. Do people simply ignore the possibility that ALL Redis instances might fail? Also, in this system, am I gaining any performance benefits by including Redis since I will be writing to MongoDB as well on each update?

Comment: The reason I am first checking Redis and THEN MongoDB is not because I expect MongoDB to have higher availability than Redis. Its because fetching from Redis will be slightly faster in this situation? (not very sure about this)

Comment: These days you can rely on Redis as you main DB (same as with Mongo), Redis has live replication and even if both replicates fail you can always restart from Redis persistence storage.